# Parametrization of an intersection cylinder ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

I'm trying to parametrize the surface given by the equations : 
$$\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}+z^2=1$$ and $x^2+y^2=y$.

I found this function :

$f:[0,1] \times [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3$, 
$$(r,x) \to \left( r \cos(x),r \sin(x),\sqrt{\frac{2-r^2}{2}} \right)$$

but Im not sure at all, can someone verify my answer

Comment: i misswrite my function, just edited it

Comment: Your parametrization covers only the "top half" of the ellipsoid given by the first equation. (Use a negative square root in the third component to get the "bottom half".) The set of points satisfying _both_ equations is a curve constituting the intersection of two surfaces, an ellipsoid and a circular cylinder. Did you want to parametrize this curve of intersection, or do you want two separate parametrizations of the surfaces?

Comment: I tried to parametrize the curve of the intersection of the two surfaces but I realize why this is just the top half of the ellipsoid.

Comment: You shouldn't reuse $x$ with a different meaning, this is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equations in cylindrical coordinates

$$x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta,z.$$

The ellipsoid becomes

$$\frac{r^2}2+z^2=1$$
or$$z=\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}2}$$
and the cylinder

$$r^2=r\sin\theta,$$or
$$r=\sin\theta.$$

Expressing all as a function of $\theta$, the parametric equation of the intersection is

$$\begin{align}x&=\sin\theta\cos\theta,\\
y&=\sin^2\theta,\\
z&=\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{\sin^2\theta}2}.
\end{align}$$

Or as a function of $r$, using $\cos\theta=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$:

$$\begin{align}x&=\pm r\sqrt{1-r^2},\\
y&=r^2,\\
z&=\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}2}.
\end{align}$$

Or as a function of $z$:

$$\begin{align}x&=\pm\sqrt{(2-2z^2)(2z^2-1)},\\
y&=2-2z^2,\\
z&=z.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I still have a question, I learned that in order to calculate the area of the surface, I have to integrate the cross product of the partial derivatives of the parametrization (don't know how to write it properly). But here I only have one variable for the parametrization so how can I do this?

Comment: Which surface ? This is a curve !

Comment: I forgot that this is only the parametrization of the curve and not the surface

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: Let $S_{1}$ be the surface with equation $\frac{1}{2}(x^{2} + y^{2}) + z^{2} = 1$ and $S_{2}$ the surface with equation $x^{2} + y^{2} = y$.

Since the equation of $S_{2}$ is independent of $z$, the surface $S_{2}$ is some "cylinder" parallel to the $z$-axis. (In fact, $S_{2}$ is a right circular cylinder, as can be checked by completing the square.) You can use polar coordinates ($x = r\cos t$, $y = r\sin t$) to parametrize the "cross section" of $S_{2}$ in the plane $z = 0$ as a polar graph $r = \phi(t)$, so that $x = \phi(t) \cos t$ and $y = \phi(t) \sin t$. Then substitute the resulting functions $(x, y)$ into the equation for $S_{1}$ to express $z$ in terms of $t$.

This works because $S_{2}$ is a cylinder parallel to the $z$-axis and $S_{1}$ is a union of graphs of $z$ as functions of $(x, y)$. A sketch of the surfaces will probably help ensure you've parametrized the entire intersection. It's also a good idea to check that your curves satisfy the equations of $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$.